# Xamarin Schedule Notifications

Tags: xamarin, alarmmanager, firebase-job-dispatcher

I wish to schedule notifications **every day** at **7:30am**, even if the phone has been rebooted or is locked.

`AlarmManager` can do the trick, but it doesn't work if the application has been dismissed/killed.

`FirebaseJobDispatcher` works too, but it doesn't fire exactly at the time you want. It fires *roughly* at the time you want it to fire.

Both approaches have drawbacks which I can't make do with.

How can I achieve this goal but have the benefits of both the approaches above? I need the notification showing regardless of if the application has been dismissed and I need it to be accurately fired at 7:30.

Comment: Your question seems more like a statement!

Comment: Do you have a try with service to do that?